# Is there a better way to deliver javascript templates to the browser than inline in the document?

Tags: javascript, templates, template-engine

I have been looking at Mustache,Handlebars and a ton of other JS templating libraries. I dont want to write my templates as text/javascript-template. Is there another way? I use Play! framework as my base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Distal templates](http://code.google.com/p/distal) which aren't written as `text/template`?

Comment: Hey Thanks for this, will take this for a test ride

Comment: Dint know about Distal so far